# Using array_filter to remove array item based on sub property value

Tags: php

Within my WordPress environemnt, I have a PHP challenege I can't wrap my brain around.  I have an array called `$tax_terms`. I want to remove the item that has a sub property of name equal to 'Staff'.

For a visual understanding, here is my array

```php
$tax_terms
```

with  `echo '<pre>' . var_export($tax_terms, true) . '</pre>';`, it prints the following to page...

```php
array (
  2 => 
  WP_Term::__set_state(array(
     'term_id' => 400,
     'name' => 'Staff',
     'slug' => 'staff',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 400,
     'taxonomy' => 'business',
     'description' => '',
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 0,
     'filter' => 'raw',
     'term_order' => '0',
  )),
  3 => 
  WP_Term::__set_state(array(
     'term_id' => 362,
     'name' => 'Customers',
     'slug' => 'Customers',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 362,
     'taxonomy' => 'business',
     'description' => '',
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 1,
     'filter' => 'raw',
     'term_order' => '0',
  )),
 
  //...more array items...

)
```

The following works when I use array_filter() on it like so...

```php
  $tax_terms = array_filter($tax_terms, function ($value) use ($tax_terms) {
    return $value != $tax_terms['2'];
  });
```

But I don't want to do it that way. I want to know what I am removing **based on the 'name' => 'Staff' value** like so...

```php
    $tax_terms = array_filter($tax_terms, function ($value) use ($tax_terms) {
      return $value != $tax_terms->name['Staff'];
    });
```

but that does not work and I don't know why yet...Thanks for helping me learn how do this right.

Comment: Why not just filter based on `$value->name != 'Staff'`?  Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Thank you Rob!  This is my first time playing with array_filters and didn't realize the flexibility was there for the return portion in that way.  Its working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$value` function argument is an entire `$tax_term` item. You need to compare the property against the string `Staff`.

```
$tax_terms = array_filter($tax_terms, function($tax_term) use($tax_terms){
    return $tax_term->name != 'Staff';
});
```

Another way would be to iterate through the `tax_terms` array using `foreach`:

```
$filtered_tax_terms = [];

foreach($tax_terms as $tax_term){
    if( $tax_term->name != 'Staff' ){
        $filtered_tax_terms[] = $tax_term;
    }
}
```